# Use result of pipeline as argument for another command

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to make part of the output of the first command as another command's argument.

Output of first command is like this, and 3000 is what I want:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
abcdefg 1020 10:30
[1000]  3000
```

I extract the pattern by `./command1 | grep '^\[' | awk 'print $2'`, so it will print out 3000, the value I want.

I'd like to make 3000 as an argument of command2 `./command2 3000`. How do I make this work?

Comment: Remember that `awk` can also do the work of `grep`, so your command could be simplified to: `./command1 | awk '/^\[/ { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to pass the input to a new command. In your example you need to include curly braces in your `awk` argument as well.

```
./command1 | grep '^\[' | awk '{ print $2 } ' | xargs ./command2
```

Or more concisely

```
.command1 | awk '/^\[/ { print $2 }' | xargs ./command2
```

Example:

```
echo "[1000]  3000" | awk '/^\[/ { print $2 }' | xargs echo
```

Output:

```
3000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
command2 $( command1 | awk '/\[/{ print $2 }' )
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also `sed`:

```
./command1 | sed -n 'n;n;p' | awk '{print $2}'
```

All together now:

```
./command2 $(./command1 | sed -n 'n;n;p' | awk '{print $2}') # ./command2 3000
```

`sed` will skip 2 lines and print the third.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try backticks first:

```
./command2 `./command1 | grep '^\[' | awk 'print $2'`
```

Comment: backticks are deprecated, you don't need grep with awk, and you've got the print in the condition instead of the action section of the awk script.

Comment: It was a quick copy-paste of the original pipeline. My fault for not checking properly. Also, +1 for pointing out backticks are deprecated. Thanks, I didn't know that myself. `$()` does require a little more typing though.

...For those who want to read more, here's a start: http://dbaspot.com/shell/392199-why-backticks-deprecated.html